# Raw and standardised x axis

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am not exactly sure if my title explains exactly what I am trying to do, but wasn't sure how to write it.

Basically, I currently have a plot with precipitation anomaly on the x-axis, and the probability of exceedance on the y-axis. I would like to add a secondary x-axis (either at the top, or underneath the current x-axis which has the standardised values marked in the right place (so Z=0 will be at -0.2, Z=1 at 8 etc). My data has a log-normal distribution, so I have done a transformation to get the log-normal distribution to be the standard normal distribution. I have the Z values in 0.2 bins from -3 to 3.

I know how to add a secondary x-axis, but the standardised values aren't linear compared to the precipitation anomaly.

I don't know if I have explained this very well, but would be grateful for some help. I can provide code for my plot so far (without the extra axis) if people wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the ticks in the secondary axis at arbitrary positions using

```
set(gca, 'XTick', tickpos)
```

and give them arbitrary labels (numeric or free text) using

```
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', tickvalues)
```

Comment: I have marked this as the answer, but the second command should say `'XTickLabel'`. I couldn't edit it myself as it was less than 6 characters.

Comment: @emmalgale, Indeed it should be. Thanks for the correction, and the upvote/accept!